# Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020

Tags: python, python-2.7

What exactly is the meaning of this warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020.
```

Comment: Python 2.7 will not have security and vulnerability patches past that point, as well as any further updates and support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves the end-of-life announcement of Python rather than being about Python programming itself.

Answer (score 2):

See [PEP 373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases):

> Being the last of the 2.x series, 2.7 will have an extended period of maintenance. Specifically, 2.7 will receive bugfix support until January 1, 2020. After the last release, 2.7 will receive no support.
>
> Planned future release dates:
>
> - 2.7.17 mid 2019
> - 2.7.18 January 2020